# Add a number by subtracting an existing number by awk

Tags: awk

I would like to convert

```
Title Page/4,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0                  
Contents/16,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

to

```
Title Page 1/4,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0                  
Contents 13/16,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

The rule is to subtract the number following `/` by 3 and add that result in front of `/`.

I tried to do that with `awk`.

```
awk -F',/' '{gsub(/\//, ($2-10) + "\/"}' myfile
```

but it doesn't work. Why is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification to your attempt produces the desired output:

```
$ awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\//, " " ($2-3) "/") }1' file
Title Page 1/4,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0                  
Contents 13/16,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

`-F` is used to specify the input field separator. I have changed it to a regex group which matches commas and slashes, which means that the second field `$2` contains the number that you are trying to replace. As you are only interested in making a single substitution in each record, I have used `sub` rather than `gsub`. Note that in awk, strings are automatically concatenated (you shouldn't use `+`).

Awk programs are stuctured like `condition { action }`. If no condition is specified, the action block is always run. If no action is specified, the default action is `{ print }`, which prints the record. In the above script, `1` is used to print the record, as it is the simplest expression that evaluates to true.

Comment: `-F'[,/]'` instead of `-F',/'` is because `[]` means OR? Does awk follow some coventions of regex, or wildchars?

Comment: @Tim It's a regex character range

Comment: "The 1 at the end always evaluates to true, so awk performs the default action". Is `1` a shortcut of something? What is the complete one?

Comment: @Tim It is just what that quote says. `1` is a truth-y value in awk and all truth-y patterns cause their respective action blocks to be run. When no action block is specified the default action block is `{print}`. So `1` is equivalent to `1{print}`. Similarly the default pattern is a true value so `{print $2}` (or whatever) is equivalent to `1{print $2}`. (I've taken to using `7` instead of `1` in this context based on another SO user as it stands out a bit more and seems a tad less magical.)

Comment: @Etan: should there be some punctuation to separate between `gsub` action  and the `print` action? e.g. `awk -F'[,/]' '{gsub(/\//, " " ($2-3) "/") }; 1' file`?

Comment: @Tim You can do that for clarity but it isn't necessary. The only thing that can occur after an action block is a pattern so the parse is unambiguous.

Comment: @Etan thanks for filling in the explanation on my behalf, I've edited so the answer itself is now more complete.